# How can I get this .c file to read a .s file and run in VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I have two files, one being main.c and the other prog2.s that contains assembly code. The commands I am running are:

gcc -Wall -g -m32 -c main.c

gcc -Wall -g -m32 -c prog2.s

gcc -Wall -g -m32 -o xtest main.o prog2.o

but on that last command, I am getting an error "undefined reference to 'prog2'" twice because in main.c, I try to call prog2 twice. I tried running the main.c file without the terminal but it produced the same error.

I'm not sure code is needed but so you get an idea of what I am trying to do, here are two code samples from each of the files up until the end of the first task which is to return j-i+2.

main.c

```
int prog2(int i, int j, int *k, int a[5], int *l);

int main() {
    int k = 6;
    int l = 0, res;
    int a[5] = {7, 0, 8, 0, 3};

    res = prog2(6,9,&k,a,&l);
    
    if(res != 9-6+2) {
        printf("return value should be=%d; got=%d\n", 9-6+2, res);
            assert(0);
    }
```

```
.globl prog2
prog2:
    #Setup Code
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl %ebx
    
    # j - i + 2
    movl 12(%ebp), %eax
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    subl %ecx, %eax
    addl $2, %eax
```

Comment: use a build tool like Make or CMake

Comment: Are you compiling for Windows, where 32-bit code uses leading underscores in the asm symbol names?  Or older MacOS where 32-bit code is possible?  MacOS also uses leading underscores.   If so, the error messages should tell you that, e.g. undefined reference to `_prog2`, which makes sense because you defined `prog2` not `_prog2`.  BTW, you forgot to `pop %ebp` / `ret`, and a closing `}` in main (also #include files).  And you don't need to separately run `gcc -c`, you can just feed it both input source files like `gcc -m32 -Wall -g -o xtest  prog2.s main.c`

Comment: Works for me on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux.  Can't reproduce your error.  I see you did quote the exact error message `"undefined reference to 'prog2'"` which doesn't have an underscore.  Are you sure you saved your `.s` file before building?